# Oracle Pivot : pivoted colums alias

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have this data :

```
drop table sample_data;
create table sample_data
(
    id_order        number  ,
    id_product      number  ,
    qty             number
);


insert into sample_data values (100,1,42);
insert into sample_data values (100,2,5);
insert into sample_data values (100,3,178);
insert into sample_data values (100,4,66);
```

Now I want to pivote the id_product values into columns

```
select *
from 
(
    select id_order, id_product, qty from sample_data
)
pivot 
(
    sum(qty) as qty 
    for (id_product) 
    in 
    (
        '1' as P01
        , '2' as P02
        , '3' as P03
        , '4' as P04
    )
)
;
```

This query aliases the pivoted columns like this :

```
  ID_ORDER    P01_QTY    P02_QTY    P03_QTY    P04_QTY
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100         42          5        178         66
```

Now, I want to alias the pivoted columns like this

```
  ID_ORDER    QTY_P01    QTY_P02    QTY_P03    QTY_P04
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100         42          5        178         66
```

Thanks in advance
Amine

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `SELECT *`, instead name your columns and provide new aliases.

```sql
select id_order,
       p01_qty AS qty_p01,
       p02_qty AS qty_p02,
       p03_qty AS qty_p03,
       p04_qty AS qty_p04
from   (
    select id_order, id_product, qty from sample_data
)
pivot (
    sum(qty) as qty 
    for (id_product) in (
        1 as P01,
        2 as P02,
        3 as P03,
        4 as P04
    )
);
```

Or, if you are only performing a single aggregation, then only define the aliases in the `IN` clause of the `PIVOT` (and not also for the aggregation):

```sql
select *
from   (
    select id_order, id_product, qty from sample_data
)
pivot (
    sum(qty)
    for (id_product) in (
        1 as QTY_P01,
        2 as QTY_P02,
        3 as QTY_P03,
        4 as QTY_P04
    )
);
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| ID_ORDER | QTY_P01 | QTY_P02 | QTY_P03 | QTY_P04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 42 | 5 | 178 | 66 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tCaa935V)